# EF6 inserting a new record including related records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following EF models:

**User.cs**

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public String UserName { get; set; }
...

public Guid UserProfileId { get; set; }
public virtual UserProfile { get; set; }
```

**Profile.cs**

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }

public String DisplayName { get; set; }
...

public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public virtual User { get; set; }
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
```

**My question**

Now, I am trying to insert a new `User` including a `Profile`. How can I insert both the `User` and the `Profile` at the same time, and "glue" the two records together?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they can be added together as your profile id gets generated when you create the user. But you certainly should be able to do this (in C#, and not tested).

```
 private readonly User usr= new User
    {
        UserName = "JohnDoe",
        Password = "janedoe"
     }

 private readonly Profile profile = new Profile
    {
        MobileNumber = "9345555555",
        Nickname = "janedoe",
        UserId = null
     }
 var db = new UserAndProfileContext();
         {                
            using (db)
            {
                var usr = new;
                db.Users.Add(usr);
                db.SaveChanges();
                profile.UserId = usr.Id;
                db.Profiles.add(profile);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Eldho's is more concise and should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

> E.g. if you want to insert a class with two students, create the Class
>   object, the Student objects, add the students to the class Students
>   collection add the Class object to the context and call SaveChanges:
>   Everything will be get saved

A blog regarding adding many to many entities [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
     var user = new User
     {
        UserName = "UserName",
        UserProfile = new UserProfile
        {
           DisplayName = "DisplayName",
        }
     };
     db.User.Add(user);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: While this solution works. The OP here won't get UserProfile Id assigned in User.

Comment: I believe the user profile id is been assigned to `userProfile` as its already know the relation. Pls correct me if i'm wrong. I had done something like this before 3 months

Comment: I tried the code below and maybe i did something wrong but the user and the profile are correctly linked each to other. but UserId and UserProfileId (as FK) stay at '0'. did you set some particular options using fluent or data annotation to achieve this ? (in a one to one relation like described by the OP)

Comment: sorry i was using database first